# Checking volatile value of address in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, raspberry-pi, volatile

I'm trying to implement a mailbox write for the Raspberry Pi. According to the info I found, I can write to address `0x2000B8A0` when mailbox is empty, meaning `0x2000B898` has not the last bit set. I wrote it like this:

```
uint32_t *mailbox = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(0x2000B880);

while((mailbox[6] & 0x80000000) != 0);

mailbox[8] = value + channel;
```

But the disassembly shows that the value at `mailbox[6]` is only loaded once, before the loop, then it just repeats the check with that one value.

I could not find a solution because I don't even know the proper words for this problem. I'm sure it's simple but googling brought nothing for this special case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer lies in title of your question.
You should use the following:

```
volatile uint32_t *mailbox = const_cast<volatile uint32_t *>(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(0x2000B880));
```

This will make sure the value is loaded each time in your loop. If you see any `application not responding`, consider adding some `sleep` or `delay` or `yield` in while.

Comment: This works. I did not know you can use `volatile` in the type of `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: `volatile` inside `reinterpret_cast` is optional. As long as `mailbox` is a `volatile *`, `mailbox[6]` would be re-loaded from memory everytime.

Comment: I would prefer using a `const_cast` to add volatile instead of reinterpret_cast.